# bootstrap scrollspy first li only is highlighted

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use scrollspy to spy on a set of dyanamically generated instructions, however it's not working. Only the first li item is highlighted regardless of page position. The body tag is as follows

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".stickysteps">
```

And then this is how scrollspy is activated

```
<% if manual.present? && manual.steps.present? %> 
<div class="stickysteps">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <% n = 0 %>
    <% @manual.steps.order(:priority).each do |step| %>
        <li><a href="#step<%= n+1 %>"><h4>Step <%= n + 1 %></h4></a></li>
        <% n += 1 %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-left: 20px;">Your Instructions:</h1> </br>
<% steps = manual.steps.order(:priority) %>
<%= render(steps.order(:priority), steps: steps) %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.stickysteps').scrollspy(); 
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
$('.stickysteps').scrollspy('refresh');
});
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom();

offsetValue = 168;
$('body').data().scrollspy.options.offset = offsetValue;
// force scrollspy to recalculate the offsets to your targets
$('body').data().scrollspy.process();
</script>
```

This is really frustrating me that I can't get this to work, it seems I've tried everything. If anyone could provide some input that would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you post a sample of your generated HTML markup intead of your template code?

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the actual HTML output.

Comment: also you should wrap your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` but you don't need to explicitly call the scrollspy plugin if you set the data-attributes to the body